# UIStoryboard application and common background image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have an iOS application which uses an UIStoryboard to control its flow. I would like to have all my views defined in the UIStoryboard to all share a common background. Is there a way I can do this without having to add an UIImageView control to each View?

I have tried this below but it causes my application crash with a stack overflow error:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyBackgroundImage.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? What is the best way to handle this kind of theming in iOS applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subclass `UIViewController` and override `-viewDidLoad` to create your image and set it as the background of the view. Now make the view controllers that require this background image subclasses of your custom view controller instead of `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewDidLoad:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[self.view addSubview: imgView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the code I posted above is working perfectly. My solution was the same as Mark Adams' suggestion: Subclass UIViewController, override -viewDidLoad, create and set the imageView, and use the new subclass as my viewController.

I think I may have inadvertently set my new subclass to an incorrect control in Interface Builder which caused my initial solution not to work correctly.